# How to get neighbor cell info from getAllCellInfo?

Tags: android, networking

this is the phone state listener i'm using to detect the changes

```
public PhoneStateListener mPhoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {


        @Override
        public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength) {
            Log.d("SIGNAL ", "  " + signalStrength.toString());
            TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) mContext.getSystemService(mContext.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            List<CellInfo> cellInfos = tm.getAllCellInfo();
            for (int i=0 ;i<cellInfos.size() ;i++)
            {
                Log.d("test ",cellInfos.get(0).toString() );
            }
        }
    };
```

The problem is currently i'm getting all cell information as below:

> result - > logs CellInfoLte:{mRegistered=YES mTimeStampType=oem_ril
>   mTimeStamp=192908703241551ns CellIdentityLte:{ mMcc=405 mMnc=869
>   mCi=2971664 mPci=123 mTac=56} CellSignalStrengthLte: ss=27 rsrp=-90
>   rsrq=-10 rssnr=2147483647 cqi=2147483647 ta=2147483647}

How can i parse this to get CellInfoLte, CellIdentityLte and CellSignalStrengthLte from the above result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're still struggling with the problem, this is the method I'm using:

```
//permission check
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity)this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},1);

    String list = "";  //I'm just adding everything to a string to display, but you can do whatever

    //get cell info
    TelephonyManager tel = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    List<CellInfo> infos = tel.getAllCellInfo();
    for (int i = 0; i<infos.size(); ++i) 
        {
            try {
                CellInfo info = infos.get(i);
                if (info instanceof CellInfoGsm) //if GSM connection
                {
                    list += "Site_"+i + "\r\n";
                    list += "Registered: " + info.isRegistered() + "\r\n";
                    CellSignalStrengthGsm gsm = ((CellInfoGsm) info).getCellSignalStrength();
                    CellIdentityGsm identityGsm = ((CellInfoGsm) info).getCellIdentity();
                    list += "cellID: "+ identityGsm.getCid() + "\r\n";
                    list += "dBm: " + gsm.getDbm() + "\r\n\r\n";
                    //call whatever you want from gsm / identitydGsm
                }
                else if (info instanceof CellInfoLte)  //if LTE connection
                {
                    list += "Site_"+i + "\r\n";
                    list += "Registered: " + info.isRegistered() + "\r\n";
                    CellSignalStrengthLte lte = ((CellInfoLte) info).getCellSignalStrength();
                    CellIdentityLte identityLte = ((CellInfoLte) info).getCellIdentity();
                    //call whatever you want from lte / identityLte
                }
                else if (info instanceof CellInfoWcdma)  //if wcdma connection
                {
                    CellSignalStrengthWcdma wcdmaS = ((CellInfoWcdma) info).getCellSignalStrength();
                    CellIdentityWcdma wcdmaid = ((CellInfoWcdma)info).getCellIdentity();
                    list += "Site_"+i + "\r\n";
                    list += "Registered: " + info.isRegistered() + "\r\n";
                    //call whatever you want from wcdmaS / wcdmaid

                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.i("neighboring error 2: " ,ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    Log.i("Info display", list);  //display everything.
```

And while we're busy, just a heads up, the LTE parsing is all screwy (you will see if you do getCi(), getTac() etc. ), so I wrote my own parsing class, and posted my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47069350/parse-getallcellinfo-values-from-telephony-manager/48324810#48324810).

Hede of warning though, when you start to see that your neighboring cell info is totally wrong... (the problem that I'm currently at), this dilemma is also posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48337100/getallcellinfo-duplicate-values). Good luck, and let me know if this part is not a issue for you

Comment: Hi  Paul, how can I get `CellInfoTdscdma`, as I have to get informarion of all type of cells.

Comment: Vote me up and I'll tell you... Haha, no sorry RG, I don't have the foggiest idea. I crash coursed through this and went on as soon as stuff "worked" for my purpose. Since then I haven't done Android dev. again, nevermind Sig str. measurements via the SDK.

Comment: Quickly tried to think about it... [CellInfoTdscdma](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellIdentityTdscdma?hl=id&refresh=1) extends cellIdentity base class, while something like [CellInfoCdma](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellInfoCdma) extends CellInfo base class. So likewise, I imagine you have List<CellIdentity> myList = **//get Cell Identity function**, and extracting CellInfoTdscdma from that. So whatever function is used to get CellIdentity data?

Comment: There is no `CellInfoTdscdma` class in android developer site. It displays only `CellIdentityTdscdma` class. I am not able to get values of identity class, because in order to get `Identity` class properties value, we must create its `CellInfo` class object.

Comment: It looked relatively straight forward to implement [CellIdentityTdscdma](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellIdentityTdscdma?hl=id&refresh=1) from a [CellIdentity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellIdentity?hl=id&refresh=1) base class, but apart from that my input is pretty useless until I would be able to experiment with myself... sorry. This was a quick proof of concept for me, so can't really remember all that much

Answer (score 0):

Try this (according to [cocorico](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2311451/cocorico)):

```
String ssignal = signalStrength.toString();
String[] parts = ssignal.split(" ");
```

Where signalStrength.toString() comes from [signalStrength](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SignalStrength.html#toString().[/link]).

The parts[] array will then contain these elements:

```
part[0] = "Signalstrength:"  _ignore this, it's just the title_
parts[1] = GsmSignalStrength
parts[2] = GsmBitErrorRate
parts[3] = CdmaDbm
parts[4] = CdmaEcio
parts[5] = EvdoDbm
parts[6] = EvdoEcio
parts[7] = EvdoSnr
parts[8] = LteSignalStrength
parts[9] = LteRsrp
parts[10] = LteRsrq
parts[11] = LteRssnr
parts[12] = LteCqi
parts[13] = gsm|lte|cdma
parts[14] = _not really sure what this number is_
```

So, LTEdBm is :

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
int dbm = 0;

if ( tm.getNetworkType() == TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE){
    // For Lte SignalStrength: dbm = ASU - 140.
    dbm = Integer.parseInt(parts[8])-140;
} else {
    // For GSM Signal Strength: dbm =  (2*ASU)-113.
    if (signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength() != 99) {
        int intdbm = -113 + 2
                        * signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength();
        dbm = Integer.toString(intdbm);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but this will only give me details regarding the serving cells not neighbor cells, i need to get values of neighbor cells

Comment: This should work:
`String s = "5476 substring=257 string"; // your string
String[] split = s.split("substring="); // substring
// String firstSubString = split[0]; // 1st part "5476 "
String secondSubString = split[1]; // 2nd part "257 string""
String finals=secondSubString.substring(0,3); // Then we get "257"` - the first 3 digits.
Change `substring=` to `mMcc=` for example.